# How to respond to "What happened to your face?"

Tags: friends, united-states, acquaintances

Long story short, this weekend while playing with my sister she ended up leaving a large scratch down my face beneath my eye. It's pretty shallow and has barely hurt, but it's very obvious (as it's almost 3 inches long).

Already today I've gotten several "What happened to your face?!" at work. Responding with "You should see the other guy." and then recapping the full story after some laughs was fun the first few times, but the novelty is wearing off.

My issue is with ending up having to retell the same story repeatedly and in the same way every time.

**How can I handle the conversation after being asked "What happened to your face?" in a way that will prevent me from having to re-explain myself in the same way every time?**

---

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be asking for suggestions on how to phrase things, which unfortunately, is off-topic here.

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel fair enough. I'm more looking for how to handle the conversation when people ask this question in a way that will prevent me from having to re-explain myself every time. Since (so far) almost everyone has asked in the same way, I suppose I'm phrasing my question for suggestions. Do you think this can be reworked to be on topic? Or better deleted??

Comment: Sure, if you rephrase it that way it stands a better chance here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the premise.. you want to say something to Person A such that Person B, independently, won't ask you about it later? Do the people asking you interact with one another?

Comment: @EmC not quite...already I've been asked on 10+ occasions today about it so I'm looking for a way to avoid having to retell the story of what happened. My work is large enough and this is a small enough deal that I doubt Person A would even mention anything to Person B. But when Person B inevitably brings it up in conversation, how can I avoid repeating myself yet again?

Comment: I guess what I don't get is what sort of solution you are looking for that *isn't* a phrasing request, can you clarify? If Person A and Person B don't talk to one another, then it doesn't matter how you tell the story to A, B is still going to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pick a version that you don't mind repeating, then simply repeat it.

I was in an accident that involved me getting 5 weeks of hospitalization and 4 months of crutches.  I simply thought of the most basic version of the story and used it for everyone that I didn't care to go into the details.